# Text-Wrapping in D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I've been researching for a while about text-wrapping, but a lot of them involve using css to text wrap?

Is there any way that I can use D3 to text wrap something like this:

```
  p.append("text")
   .attr("transform", "translate(-20, -30)")
   .text("Relevance")
   .style("font", "bold 12px Arial");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `svg:foreignObject` with an HTML `div` or similar to make this work. SVG itself won't wrap the text.

Comment: `svg:foreignObject` is not supported by any version of IE. Chrome also doesn't support transforms on `foreignObject`.

Comment: using foreignObject is not the best solution for this issue. follow @user879121

Answer (score 1):

I assume `p` is not already an xhtml element here. If it's some svg element like `g` you may append `foreignObject` to it and then afterwards append xhtml elements like div like in following code.

```
p = svg.append('g');
p.append("foreignObject")
 .attr("x", 5)
 .attr("y", 5) 
 .attr("width", 100) // replace with width you want 
 .attr("height", 100)// replace with height you want
 .append("xhtml:div")// replace with html element you want
 .append("p")
 .text("Relevance");
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers recommend using `svg:foreignObject`. Sadly no version of IE supports `foreignObject`, not even the latest (being 11 at the time of writing). Support across other browsers is inconsistent with some not supporting transitions. So, if you don't need transitions and don't need to support IE then you can use the `foreignObject`; it's the easiest method because it supports HTML + CSS.

Otherwise, if you need IE support or transitions...

Mbostock has an example for [Wrapping Long Labels](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321). It can be adapted for wrapping text in other situations, though it's not trivial.

[D3plus](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus) supports [text wrapping](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Text%20Wrapping) like so:

```
d3plus.textwrap()
  .container(d3.select("#rectWrap"))
  .draw();
```

I've used D3plus. It's very easy to use. But D3plus has other features you probably don't want so you might also consider [d3textwrap](https://github.com/vijithassar/d3textwrap), a plugin that only adds text wrapping.